# SciChart Xamarin.iOS: PointMarker Tap Event

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, scichart

Is it possible to capture the tap event when we tap on a point marker or a data point? I can see there’s a DataPointSelectionModifier for WPF, but there’s nothing for iOS. Our goal is to show a popup (tooltip) on the point marker when the user taps on it.

Thanks,
Lazar Nikolov

Xamarin.iOS Package Version: **2.2.2.854**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you are looking for is called the Hit-Test API.

In the latest (sciChart iOS v3) the [documentation link is here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/current/hit-test-api.html):

```
private void HandleSingleTap(UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    // The touch point relative to the SCIChartSurface
    var location = recognizer.LocationInView(recognizer.View.Superview);
    // Translate the touch point relative to RenderableSeriesArea (or ModifierSurface)
    var hitTestPoint = SciChartSurface.TranslatePoint(location, Surface.RenderableSeriesArea);
    // Perform `Hit-Test` which will be stored in the `_hitTestInfo`
    renderableSeries.HitTest(_hitTestInfo, hitTestPoint);
}
```

We also have an example showing how to use the [Hit-Test API here](https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-chart-chart-hit-test-api-example/). It is Swift but the principles in Xamarin are the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We had trouble with the current version of SciChart at that time. The Hit-Test results were always "true" so we couldn't zero in on what the data point was tapped on.

Comment: Interesting, if you still experience problems contact scichart support (if in subscription) and they will be glad to help